# Parsing JSON array key/values in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Would you advise if I can parson repeated JSON key/value array as separate columns? My goal is, having a record with three columns from the key. All three key names are not duplicated in the original JSON. Can I get your thought?

```
-- create a sample table
create or replace table json_example(v variant);
-- create sample json record
insert into json_example
select parse_json(
    '{"event_params": [{"key": "firebase_previous_id", "value": { "int_value": "6360478777384052472"}},{"key": "firebase_screen_class","value": {"string_value": "Flutter"}},{"key": "firebase_event_origin","value": {"string_value": "auto"}}]}'
);

-- the query I created (not going well)
select
    ep.key.firebase_previous_id.int_value::varchar as firebase_previous_id,
    ep.key.firebase_screen_class.string_value::varchar as firebase_screen_class,
    ep.key.firebase_event_origin.string_value::varchar as firebase_event_origin
from
    json_example,
    lateral flatten(input => v, outer => true) ep
```

Comment: For future readers. Please refer to this link. https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009E51JMSAZ/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-into-columns-instead-of-rows

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you want then you can get the values from value as value:

```
select value from (
select parse_json(
    '{"event_params": [{"key": "firebase_previous_id", "value": { "int_value": "6360478777384052472"}},{"key": "firebase_screen_class","value": {"string_value": "Flutter"}},{"key": "firebase_event_origin","value": {"string_value": "auto"}}]}'
)) as src,
lateral flatten(input => src.$1:event_params);
```

Comment: What I was looking for was combining such flattened rows as a single row. But I found the way. But thanks for your help!!
https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009E51JMSAZ/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-into-columns-instead-of-rows